# Как сделать, чтобы начальная позиция в скролл была в середине?

Tags: html, прокрутка, css

Как сделать, чтобы начальная позиция в скролл была в середине? Чтобы начиналась не с левого угла, а с середины.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать с помощью яваскрипта, при открытии странички запускать скрипт и в нем `scrollTop` со своими параметрами.

Comment: $(selector).scrollleft(position); проблема решена